# Is it a good idea to run Apache on Windows server 2012?

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, iis

I run AmazonWebService with: Windows Server 2012 + IIS + Python3 website and want to add django. I tried to find some tutorial how to do it, but unfortunately, found nothing.

Is it a good idea to install Apache on Windows Server 2012 and then try to deploy django on it? How difficult is it?

Thanks

Comment: It can be done, but it can be problematic. Here is a tutorial on running Django with IIS http://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial My advise would be to use a Linux server, I like an easy life, but that's just me!

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I can not use Linux. So my alternative is either (1) deploy django with IIS (2) install Apache on windows and then deploy django on it. What do you think would be better?

Comment: Windows is designed for IIS, I haven't done it myself but know devs who have and was told it's pain. You have to override a lot of things that IIS wants to own. I personally would stick with IIS when using Windows. http://chrisberragan.com/posts/2014/03/19/installing-django-on-iis-7-5/

Comment: Thank you very much! (+1) I was trying to install django on IIS but got stuck (I even tried to find a freelancer to do it for me)....